# npm install issues inside a container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm-install, node-gyp

I am trying to run npm install inside a container that starting FROM node:17.5-bullseye-slim. I can run npm install on the host without problems but it fails in the container. My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM node:17.5-bullseye-slim

ENV TZ=America/Chicago
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive


WORKDIR /usr/src/[directory_name]

COPY package*.json ./

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y python3; \
    apt-get install -y python2 make; \
    apt-get install -y g++; \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python; \
    npm install

COPY . .
```

This is the error that comes out of the process:

```
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.4.1 -> 8.5.1
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.5.1>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@8.5.1` to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/src/poolapi/node_modules/epoll
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.5.0 | linux | arm
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.5.0/node-v17.5.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN nodejs.org
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:72:26)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.63-v7+
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/src/poolapi/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /usr/src/poolapi/node_modules/epoll
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.5.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: The error is being thrown by npm install, any chance you can post the repo, it'll help debug it.

Comment: It looks like the error that is thrown (Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN nodejs.org) is a dns lookup error. I added a step to my Dockerfile that installs wget and then does a wget against the address that seems to be failing (https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.5.0/node-v17.5.0-headers.tar.gz) - wget worked AND it also prevents the error from happening in npm install. I am thinking maybe nodejs.org dns is cached after the wget so npm install works without the dns lookup error???

Comment: @NateJohnson I am facing same issue but using wget is resulting in operation timed out. Do you have any other solution? I am pretty new yo Docker

Answer (score -2):

It helped for me:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install build-essential -y
```

It option also worked:

```
FROM node:16-bullseye-slim
RUN  apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y python3; \
    apt-get install -y python2 make; \
    apt-get install -y g++; \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python;
```